# How to use mybatis to return a table or setof from procedure call with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

How can I solve it use mybatis to return a table or setof from procedure call with postgresql. thanks
psotgreaql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.p_find_battery_detail(
item character varying, 
vaulestr character varying, 
islimit boolean)
 RETURNS TABLE(
id bigint, 
no character varying, 
chassis character varying, 
channel character varying, 
module character varying, 
isformat bit, 
isgrad bit, 
ismatch bit, 
ismastop bit, 
sfile json, 
sftimesign character varying, 
groupclass character varying, 
gradtimesign character varying, 
gradf json)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

mybatis in java wiht annotation

```
@Select("call p_find_battery_detail(#{0}, #{1}, #{2})")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
List<BatteryInfoDetail> findBatteryDetail(String itemStr, String valueStr, boolean isLimit);
```

when i run this serch, will throw some error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter '0' not found. Available parameters are [arg2, arg1, arg0, param3, param1, param2]
and so on....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shortest way to go forward is to apply the hint provided by error message:

```
@Select("call p_find_battery_detail(#{arg0}, #{arg1}, #{arg2})")
```

to go farther you name parameters by annotation to reuse this name in query:

```
@Select("call p_find_battery_detail(#{itemStr}, #{valueStr}, #{isLimit})")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
List<BatteryInfoDetail> findBatteryDetail(@Param("itemStr") String itemStr, Param("valueStr") String valueStr, Param("isLimit") boolean isLimit);
```

params may have any name you want.

Comment: thank you for you answer. but i use your plan also throw error.At the same time, I remembered the Postgresql function can be obtained by the select * from data. Finally I have modified the statement after successful return a value

Comment: indeed `@Select("SELECT * FROM p_find_battery_detail(#{0}, #{1}, #{2})")` is a better way to call function and will error for same reason (parameters names) then eventually: `@Select("SELECT * FROM  p_find_battery_detail(#{arg0}, #{arg1}, #{arg2})")`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Select("select * from  p_find_battery_detail(#{itemStr}, #{valueStr}, #{isLimit})")
List<BatteryDetail> findAll(@Param("itemStr") String itemStr, @Param("valueStr") String valueStr, @Param("isLimit") boolean isLimit);
```